# ERROR: 0:1: '' : Version number not supported by GL2

Tags: c++, glsl, shader

I'm trying to make shader, but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: 0:1: ' ' :  Version number not supported by GL2
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error parse error
```

Please help!
This is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330
        
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
void main()
{
gl_Position = position;
}
```

And this is my fragment shader code:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
void main()
{
color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I tried making the version lower, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your shader doesn't make any sense. `position` is not declared, `color` is never set and layout location are not supported in GLSL 1.50

Comment: This is only the vertex shader.

Comment: I will upload my fragment shader. Sorry, i forgot about it

Comment: My videocard support only versions before opengl 2.0

Comment: What versions support layout and location?

Comment: Since your graphics card only supports OpenGL 2.0, you cannot use a version that supports layout locations. However, there seems to be something wrong with your system. OpenGL 2.0 is about 20 years old. Is your graphics driver up to date?

Comment: Yes, my graphics driver is up to date. My videocard is so old, i think this is the problem. Windows 8 don't support my drivers :(

Comment: I will try to run it on my other laptop.

Comment: It didnt work on my other laptop! It gives me errors, because of missing dll files. Do i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your graphics driver and card only support OpenGL 2.0, you cannot use a GLSL shader with version 3.30. You need to use GLSL 1.10 which corresponds to OpenGL 2.0.
See [OpenGL Shading Language 1.10 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.10.pdf) and [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)

An appropriate shader would be:

Vertex shader

```c
#version 110
        
attribute vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
#version 110

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying many versions without success.